# What is the formal name for an autonomous dynamical system whose control input depends on its state?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

What is the formal name for a dynamical system whose dynamics are a function of its state $\bf x$ and control input $\bf u$, where the control input is a function of the state, i.e., $\bf u(x)$. In essence,

$$\dot{\bf x} = \bf f ( x, u ( x ) )$$

In my case, $\bf u(x)$ is represented by a nonlinear function, namely, a neural network.

Comment: I would call it *state feedback control*.

Comment: I suppose it would be called an *autonomously controlled* autonomous dynamical system.